# Error when starting Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What does this error mean please?

```
Stack named 'awseb-eea9ufee4ak-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition]. (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: OperationError; Request ID: null)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that launching your environment timed out while waiting to hear back the EC2 instance. The instance did not report whether it successfully launched the environment or not. I would recommend taking snapshot logs to see detailed error messages from the instance.

Comment: *Can* you get the logs from the instance if it's been terminated?

Comment: no you cannot get logs from an EC2 instance after it has been terminated.